# output neighbouring lines with line numbers while grepping

Tags: text-processing, grep

Is there a way to output the neighbouring lines along with the line numbers while grepping the contents of a file? I'm trying to get outputs of the form:

```
$ ~/myscript.sh download file # 'download' being the pattern here
121: # and downloads with wget/curl, whichever is available.
122: download_file () {
123:  if which wget &>/dev/null; then
----------
356: # Since the prerequisites are already installed, we may proceed
357: download_urls=("http://example.com/foo/bar.bz2"
358:                "http://d1.example.com/xyz/abc.tar.gz"
```

Of course, I know that I can get grep my pattern with the `-n` option and show some of the neighbouring lines from the obtained line number (say, by using any of the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file)), but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GNU `grep`'s Context Line Control, from `man grep`:

> -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
>               Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group  separator  (--)  between  contiguous  groups  of
>               matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
>
>        -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
>               Print  NUM  lines  of  leading  context  before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of
>               matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

If you require an equal number of lines either side, you can use a single context number:

> -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
>               Print NUM lines of output context.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches.   With  the  -o  or
>               --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

When combined with the `-n` flag (`--line-number`), you have numbered matches with surrounding context.

In your example:

```
grep -n -C1 download
```